# Field fixing automorphism

Tags: field-theory

Determine all the field fixing automorphism of the field extension Kron[$Z2,x^4+x+1$]. I got three functions, but I am not sure if there is more.

Comment: Kron${}{}{}{}$?

Comment: $x^4+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $Z2$, Then Kron[$Z2,x^4+x+1$] is an extension field  with sixteen elements $Z2[r]$.

Comment: So this is $\Bbb F_{16}$. Every extension of finite fields is Galois.

Comment: Yes, it is. The elements of this field are: {$0,1,r,r+1,r^2,r^2+1,r^2+r,r^2+r+1, r^3,r^3+1, r^3+r,r^3+r+1,r^3+r^2,r^3+r^2+1,r^3+r^2+r,r^3+r^2+r+1$}